# Interview Friendly Linked List C++

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, data-structures, nodes

In a language like JavaScript, to create a Linked List, you can do this:

```js
class Node() {
  constructor(value, next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

var LL1 = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3, new Node(4, null))));
```

What is nice about this for interviews is that you don't have to keep track of when you need to free memory.

With an example of something similar in C++:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Node {
  Node() = delete;

  Node(const T value, Node<T> *next)
  : value(value), next(next) {};

  T value;
  Node<T> *next;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Node<int> *LL1 = new Node<int>(1, new Node<int>(2, new Node<int>(3, new Node<int>(4, nullptr))));

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not properly freeing the memory here.

Is there a way I can write my `Node` class so that I don't have to keep references to `new Node<T>`s in order to `delete` them later?

The only way I know of doing it is like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Node<int> *node4 = new Node<int>(4, nullptr);
  Node<int> *node3 = new Node<int>(3, node4);
  Node<int> *node2 = new Node<int>(2, node3);
  Node<int> *LL1 = new Node<int>(1, node2);

  delete node4;
  delete node3;
  delete node2;
  delete LL1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: This is C++. In an "interview" i wouldn't write a linked list class to begin with. I'd tell the interviewer I'll be using `std::list<T>` and move on to things that actually need engineering time rather than unnecessarily reinventing the wheel for the millionth time. If they *still* want me to reinvent that wheel, so be it, but that's a testimonial to something for certain, and it most-certainly is *not* my engineering skills.

Comment: I am confused. The syntax you provide at the end of the post should work in c++. As to freeing the memory, look into `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: In a linked list, you don't generally expose the nodes in the first place. So the user of your list should never have to deal with managing the memory, the class would do that on its own.

Comment: Agree @WhozCraig but in the case where the problem is like: In a sorted linked list [1, 2, 3, 4], add a new node in its correct position. You wouldn't use std::list in that case to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Lala5th yes it does compile and you can loop through a list this way but it does not properly deal with freeing memory I would think.

Comment: @RyanSam [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rxTPhz4Gr) would free the memory. It's an ugly hack though

Comment: @RyanSam You can free from the down up. Go through until you find the bottom and free it. Repeat until you have nothing to free

Comment: "add a new node in its correct position" I would not use any kind of linked list to maintain a sorted sequence. (I would not use any kind of linked list to do almost anything). However it isn't clear why you would prefer to roll your own list to do this (fundamentally stupid and pointless) demonstration. How is `std::list` *even less* suitable for this than any other list implementation?

Comment: @RyanSam I absolutely would, if that was the request. I'd just use the standard library to do it. It ain't hard to iterate to a position and insert a value, and that's all build-by-insert in a linked data structure does when sort-as-you go is the ask.

Comment: @RyanSam Look at the API for `std::list` and `std::forward_list`. You don't see any mention of "nodes" in the API for those. The user only has to care about the actual `T`:s in the list and the nodes carrying the `T`s are hidden implementation details. You have _iterator_ s instead of raw node pointers and you don't need to (or should) `delete` those.

Comment: One thing you could do is add a destructor to your `Node` class like this:  `~Node() {delete next;}` ... then you'd only need to remember to call `delete` on the head of your linked list; all of the other Nodes in the list would be deleted recursively via the destructor-calls.

Comment: While I understand that usually the low level handling of the nodes is hidden from the user like in the case of std::list. I feel like the point is being missed here on what I'm asking. If I need to clarify more I will try my best. Not saying I agree with how interviews are conducted 100% of the time, but simple linked list questions where you need to write a node class are common, including at top companies. In c++ though, any operations on a linked list becomes more difficult when I am also trying to properly free memory. For example a function that mutates a linked list.

Comment: @RyanSam The best way to free memory is to let the language handle it for you. You already discovered that in JS. In C++, stay away from *manual* calls to `new` and `delete` whenever possible. If you need to allocate things dynamically, use smart pointers, or containers that handle dynamic memory for you. "*In a sorted linked list [1, 2, 3, 4], add a new node in its correct position. You wouldn't use std::list in that case to demonstrate this*" - why not? `std::list` has an [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) method to add a value anywhere within the list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In an interview setting you wouldn't do that. Because it doesn't convey to the interviewer your understanding of how operations on a linked list work.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner a recursive destructor would be fine for this particular example, but in general should never be used in production code, as destroying a long list could lead to a stack overflow at runtime. I would expect an interviewer to mark down for that.

Comment: @RyanSam why not? It conveys that you actually understand your chosen tool (C++) and how it is meant to be used. and what it is capable of. And you can certainly write code using `std::list` that conveys your understanding of linked lists, without getting into the nitty gritty low-level details of memory management that most production code won't delve deep into anyway. Production code should be written in a safe manner, and in modern C++ that means NOT managing memory manually, unless you absolutely must (custom allocators, memory pooling, etc).

Comment: @RyanSam If you REALLY want to convey to an interviewer that you understand how linked lists work, you could always just declare a fixed sized array of `Node` objects, and then link them together. No memory to allocate or free manually, but you still have the benefit of showing use of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can write my `Node` class so that I don't have to keep references to `new Node<T>`s in order to delete them later?

Yes - you could use (in this example, a fixed sized) array to hold the `Node` objects with [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), so they get destroyed automatically at program exit.  Then simply link the `Node`s together before using them, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Node {
  Node() = default;

  Node(const T &value, Node<T> *next = nullptr)
    : value(value), next(next) { }

  T value{};
  Node<T> *next = nullptr;
};

int main() {
  Node<int> nodes[4];

  Node<int> *node4 = &nodes[3];
  *node4 = Node<int>(4);
  Node<int> *node3 = &nodes[2];
  *node3 = Node<int>(3, node4);
  Node<int> *node2 = &nodes[1];
  *node2 = Node<int>(2, node3);
  Node<int> *LL1 = &nodes[0];
  *LL1 = Node<int>(1, node2);

  /* alternatively:

  Node<int> *next = nullptr;
  for(int i = 3; i >= 0; --i) {
    nodes[i] = Node<int>(i+1, next);
    next = &nodes[i];
  }

  Node<int> *LL1 = &nodes[0];
  */

  // use LL1 as needed...

  return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/JhBNrk)

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/GK0OoF)

Comment: I suppose instead of using a fixed sized array I could also use a std::vector here too?

Comment: Yes, a `vector` would work, too. Just be careful that you fill the `vector` with `Node`s before you link up their `next` pointers, otherwise if you make the `vector` grow afterwards then you will have to re-link the pointers since the `Node`s would have been moved to new memory.

Comment: Are you saying I couldn't dynamically add nodes to a vector once I've linked them? In other words when the vector resizes all my links become invalid?

Comment: @RyanSam if you `reserve()` the `vector`'s capacity before adding `Node`s to it, and you don't exceed that capacity when adding `Node`s, then the `vector` will not need to re-allocate its internal memory, and so you won't need to re-link any `Node*` pointers.  But, if the `vector`'s size ever exceeds its capacity, the internal memory will re-allocate, and you will have to re-link all existing `Node*` pointers. In that scenario, it would be better to use indexes instead of pointers.

Comment: In that case I really don't see the advantage of using a vector over a fixed sized array.

Comment: @RyanSam in this simple example, no. But let's say you wanted to pre-allocate a much larger array. It would be better to store it in dynamic memory instead of in local memory on the call stack.

Comment: So if I want to insert a new element into the list and my fixed sized array is full I need to (1.) create a new larger array (2.) copy all the nodes from prev array into new array (3.) then relink them? Or I could just have a vector handle all that resize jazz but still relink `if  vector.size() + 1 > vector.capacity()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244316/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ryan-sam).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing C++ for real (as in for a real job), then you should always use RAII.  Failure to do so is often considered equivalent to a bug in practice, and will make you look bad in an interview.

Nobody ever really makes a linked list class, but if you have to for an interview, and you want to use Nodes as lists in client code, then you should arrange for each node to *own* the next node.  Destroying a node should automatically clean up anything that it owns.

In modern C++, we don't have to *remember* to delete stuff anymore.

You should also make sure that destroying a node doesn't recurse into the destructors for all the next nodes, because a linked list on the heap may have enough nodes to overflow the stack.

```
template<typename T> class Node {
  public:
  Node(const T &value, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> &&next)
    : value(value), next(next) { }
  ~Node() {
    // delete the chain iteratively to avoid stack overflow
    while (next) {
      // this assignment deletes the node that next points to
      // and replaces it with the following node.
      next = next->detach_next();
    }
  }
  Node<T> *get_next() const {
    return next.get();
  }
  std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> detach_next() {
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> ret(std::move(next));
    next.reset();
    return ret;
  }
  const T &get_value() const {
    return value;
  }
  T &get_value() {
    return value;
  }

  private:
  T value;
  std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> next;
};
```

You can then make and use your list like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::unique_ptr<Node<int>> list;
  list.reset(new Node<int>(4,std::move(list));
  list.reset(new Node<int>(3,std::move(list));
  list.reset(new Node<int>(2,std::move(list));
  list.reset(new Node<int>(1,std::move(list));

  for (Node<int> *n = list.get(); n; n = n->get_next()) {
    std::cout << n->get_value() << std::endl;
  }
  //everything gets cleaned up here
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of constructing a list?

Comment: I added example construction and iteration.